# Table design and Querying

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table design that is represented by this awesome hand drawn image.

[image]

Basically, I have an account event, which can be either a Transaction (Payment to or from a third party) or a Transfer (transfer between accounts held by the user).

All common data is held in the event table (`Date`, `CreatedBy`, `Source Account Id`...) and then if it's a transaction, then transaction specific data is held in the Account Transaction table (Third Party, transaction type (`Debit`, `Credit`)...). If the event is a transfer, then transfer specific data is in the account_transfer table (`Amount`, `destination account id`...).

Note, something I forgot to draw, is that the Event table has an `event_type_id`. If `event_type_id = 1`, then it's a **transaction**. If it's a `2`, then it's a **Transfer**.

Both the transfer and transaction tables are linked to the event table via an event id foreign key.

Note though that a transaction doesn't have an amount, as the transaction can be split into multiple payment lines, so it has a child account_transaction_line. To get the amount of the transaction, you sum it's child lines.

Foreign keys are all setup, with an index on primary keys...

My question is about design and querying. If I want to list all events for a specific account, I can either:

```
Select 
from Event, 
where event_type = 1 (transaction), 
then INNER join to the Transaction table,
 and INNER join to the transaction line (to sum the total)... 
 and then UNION to another selection, 
selecting 
from Event,
 where event_type = 2 (transfer),
 INNER join to transfer table... 
 and producing a list of all events.
```

or

```
Select 
from Event, 
then LEFT join to transaction, 
then LEFT join to transaction line,
 then LEFT join to transfer ... 
 and sum up totals (because of the transaction lines).
```

Which is more efficient? I think option 1 is best, as it avoids the LEFT joins (Scans?)

OR...

An Indexed View of option 1?

Comment: Plus 1 for the hand drawn schema, but I see no reason for separate tables for transfers and transactions.  With a bit more thought into the design, your queries could be a lot simpler.

Comment: I was thinking of a single transaction table, but my thought was that, a transfer, and a transaction seem different. They have common fields, but they have a lot of fundamental differences. One goes to a Third Party (nullable), one has a Destination Account (Nullable), a transaction can be split into many lines, where a transfer is a one liner (I can just have a line per transfer too, instead of an amount in the transfer table). I can change to a single table... but was trying to avoid all the nullable redundant columns. If that would be more efficient, then I can still change my design.

Comment: To have a single table, I'd need numerous LEFT joins to my Third Party, Account table (for the destination account)... transaction type (credit/debit) would be not needed for transfer (Uses source and destination). Adding all the nullable columns, forcing left joins - is that not less efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On performance**

For performance analysis in SQL server, there are quite a few factors at play, e.g.

- What is the number of queries you are going to run, esp. on the same data? For example, if 80% of your queries are around 20% of your data, then caching may help significantly. (See below the design section on how this can matter)
- Are your databases distributed or collocated on the same server? I assume it's a single server system, but if they were distributed, the design and optimization might vary.
- Are these queries executed in a background process or on-demand and a user is expecting to get the results quicker?

Without these (and perhaps some other follow up questions once answers to these are provided), it would be unwise to give an answer stating one being preferable over the other.

Having said that, based on my personal experience, your best bet specifically for SQL server is to use [query analyzer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216945%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx), which is actually pretty reasonable, as your first stop. After that, you can do some performance analyses to find the optimal solution. Typically, these are done by [modeling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647767.aspx) the query traffic as it would be when the system is under regular load. (FYI: The modeling link is to ASP.NET performance modeling, but various core concepts apply to SQL as well.) You typically put the system under load and then:

- Look at how many connections are lost -- this can increase if the queries are expensive.
- Performance counters on the server(s) to see how the system is dealing with the load.
- Responses from the queries to see if some start failing to provide a valid response, although this is unlikely to happen

FYI: This is based on my personal experience, after having done various types of performance analyses for multiple projects. We expect to do it again for our current project, although this time around we're using AD and Azure tables instead of SQL, and hence the methodology is not specific to SQL server, although the tools, traffic profiles, and what to measure varies.

**On design**

*Introducing event id in the account transaction line:*
Although you do not explicitly state so, but it seems that the event ID and transaction ID is not going to change after the first entry has been made. If that's the case and you are only interested in getting the totals for a transaction in this query, then another option (which will optimize your queries) would be to add a foreign key to AccountEvent's primary key (which I think is the event id). In strictest DB sense, you are de-normalizing the table a bit, but in practice, it often helps with performance.

*Computing totals on inserts:*
The other approach that I have taken in a past project (just because I was using FoxPro in the previous century and FoxPro tended to be extremely slow at joins) was to keep total amounts in the primary table, equivalent of your transactions table. This would be quite useful if your reads heavily outweighed your writes, and in the case of SQL, you can issue a transaction to make entries in other tables and update totals simultaneously (hence my question about on your query profiles).

*Join transaction & transfers tables:*
Keep a value to indicate which is which, and keep the totals there -- similar to previous one but at a different level. This will decrease the joins on query, but still have sum of totals on inserts -- I would prefer the previous over this one.

*De-normalize completely:*
This is yet another approach that folks have used (esp. in NOSQL space), but it gives me shivers when applying in SQL Server, so I have a personal bias against it but you could very well search it and find about it.

Comment: Thanks @Omar. I'll look into what you're saying. Storing computed values and adding the event id to the transaction line table seems against design principles - but may work. I need to investigate that. My biggest issue with my current design, in the awesome diagram, is the LEFT JOINS I'd need. I'm uncertain about their performance. Moving to one table is another option, but again, there will be loads of null fields, requiring left joins. Really battling with the options.

Comment: Sure, np. Probably worth prototyping: you could spend a day or two and create 2-3 different DBs with various options and try them. Often seeing in real makes a big difference (akin to picture is a thousand words :-)). Also, I am not sure what design principle is keeping totals in the main table against? Probably articulating the pros/cons in a table might also help because sometimes, we're also dealing with our personal biases in addition to genuine design challenges (like this one).